# (Python, Selenium WD) Нow to receive and transfer the list to a cycle?

Tags: python, selenium, cycle

I have this code

```
lst = ["Appearence","Logotype", "Catalog", "Product Groups", "Option Groups","Manufacturers","Suppliers",
   "Delivery Statuses","Sold Out Statuses", "Quantity Units", "CSV Import/Export", "Countries","Currencies","Customers"]

for item in lst:
    wd.find_element_by_link_text(item).click()
    assert wd.title != None
```

I not want to write list by hand.
I want to receive the list - lst directly from the browser.
I use

```
m = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[id=app-]')
print(m[0].text)

Appearence
```

I don't know how to transfer the list to a cycle

look this picture [screen browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5A7D.png)

Please help me to understand how to use the list and to transfer it to a cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example variable `m` will be a list of WebElements you get the length of it and iterate CSS pseudo selector `:nth-child()` with a range:

```
m = wd.get_elements_by_css_selector('li#app-')

for elem in range(1, len(m)+1):
    wd.get_element_by_css_selector('li#app-:nth-child({})'.format(elem)).click()
    assert wd.title is not None
```

In the for loop it will iterate over a range of integers starting with 1 and ending with the length of the element list (+1 because is not inclusive), the we will click the nth-child of the selector using the iterating number, `.format(elem)` will replace th `{}` appearance in the string for the elem variable, in this case the integer iteration.

Comment: `.format()` will replace any appearances of `{}` by the variables passed to it in their respective order. More info :https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format